# Angular 9 How can I wait until request is done

Tags: angular

I have a health check-in my app that pings the server every 4 seconds when the database connection is lost the health check response takes about 15 seconds, so I am getting to the situation when DB connection is lost there are no response returns

How can I wait until my HTTP request completed without increasing poll interval, maybe there another way to handle it

**Service**

```
 constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

    getConsoleHealth(): Observable<any> {

        return this.httpClient.get(BASE_SERVICE_URL +'/health', {
            headers: headers
        });
    }

    pollConsoleHealth(initialDelay: number, pollInterval: number): Observable<ActuatorHealth> {

        return timer(initialDelay, pollInterval)
            .pipe(

                switchMap(() => this.getConsoleHealth(),
                )
            );
    }
```

**component**

```
 loadConsoleHealth(): void {
        this.serviceSubscription = this.service.pollConsoleHealth(0, 4000)
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.consoleHealth = data;
            }, error  => {

            }
            );
    }
```

Comment: so you want it like that once first response is there then wait for 4 seconds then go for next request?

Comment: well yes, its send a request ->get a response(here its can take more than 4 seconds ), send a new request after 4 seconds

Comment: I am not sure entirely in what you want but try changing the `switchMap` to `concatMap`. `switchMap` cancels the previous request and goes with a new request, `concatMap` waits in order. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51171194/angular-5-rxjs-concatmap-switchmap-mergemap-which

Comment: can you try my solution below?

Comment: @ AliF50 Thank you I was able to find an answer, changing the switchMap to concatMap did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ AliF50 Thank you I was able to make it work, changing the switchMap to concatMap did the trick

```
 pollConsoleHealth(initialDelay: number, pollInterval: number): Observable<ActuatorHealth> {
        return timer(initialDelay, pollInterval)
            .pipe(
                concatMap(() => this.getConsoleHealth(),
                )
            );
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

In the code below i have made an recursive call. In first call it will respect initial delay, after that it will only respect pollinterval and will poll after waiting till pollinterval but after receiving response

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { delay, switchMap, map, mergeMap } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = "Angular 6";

  ngOnInit() {
    this.pollConsoleHealth(1000, 4000).subscribe();
  }
  getConsoleHealth(): Observable<any> {
    console.log("next Call" + new Date());
    return of("newData").pipe(delay(20000));
  }

  pollConsoleHealth(
    initialDelay: number,
    pollInterval: number
  ): Observable<any> {
    return of([]).pipe(
      delay(initialDelay),
      delay(pollInterval),
      switchMap(() =>
        this.getConsoleHealth().pipe(
          switchMap(res => this.pollConsoleHealth(0, pollInterval))
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Stackblitz url :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-vivvvz

Comment: tried that getting compilation errors Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<unknown>'.ts(2339) on the first pipe and            
   Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.ts(2345)

Comment: wait 1 minute. let me check

Comment: i have a hard time to follow this pice of code, still not compiles                                     type 'Observable<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<ActuatorHealth>': then, catch, [Symbol.toStringTag], finally

Comment: i have added complete code above with a stackblitz url, check browser dev console as well.

Comment: Go to stackblitz url given above and open dev tools you can see that statement printing.

Comment: really impressive! I am checking this out

Comment: Still doesn't solve the problem pollConsoleHealth called only once, expected every 4 seconds depends on response time. the best way to demo this is to put a delay of 20 seconds on getConsoleHealth method and try to call it every 4 seconds from pollConsoleHealth

Comment: Hello @MariaFinkelstein, i have updated the code above and in stackblitz as per demo wanted by you. and also have reduced code in pollConsoleHealth method. hope this serves your purpose.

Comment: I was able to find an answer, changing the switchMap to concatMap did the trick,one line code change thank you very much for your help

Comment: but please check the answer above and if produces same result, then vote for it so that others looking for same can be benefited.